# Request is not send without block()

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I want to use this webflux client code to send POST requests with reply and without reply. I tried this code implementation:

```
public class RestClientBuilder {
    private String token;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private URL gatewayUrl;
    private SslContextBuilder sslContextBuilder;

    public static RestClientBuilder builder() {
        return new RestClientBuilder();
    }

    public RestClientBuilder token(String token) {
        this.token = validateAndTrim(token, "Token");
        return this;
    }

    public RestClientBuilder usernamePassword(String username, String password) {
        this.username = validateAndTrim(username, "Username");
        this.password = validateAndTrim(password, "Password");
        return this;
    }

    private String validateAndTrim(String value, final String parameter) {
        if (value == null || value.trim().isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(parameter + " is empty");
        }
        return value.trim();
    }

    public RestClientBuilder gatewayUrl(String gatewayUrl) {
        String urlSt = validateAndTrim(gatewayUrl, "Gateway URL");
        try {
            this.gatewayUrl = new URL(urlSt);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Malformed URL: " + urlSt, e);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public RestClientBuilder truststore(File truststoreFile) {
        getSslContextBuilder().trustManager(truststoreFile);
        return this;
    }

    public RestClientBuilder sslCertificate(File keyCertChainFile, File keyFile, String keyPassword) {
        getSslContextBuilder().keyManager(keyCertChainFile, keyFile, keyPassword);
        return this;
    }

    public RestClient build() throws SSLException {
        SslContext sslContext = sslContextBuilder != null ? sslContextBuilder.build() : null;
        return new RestClient(gatewayUrl.toString(), token, username, password, sslContext);
    }

    private SslContextBuilder getSslContextBuilder() {
        if (sslContextBuilder == null) {
            sslContextBuilder = SslContextBuilder.forClient();
        }
        return sslContextBuilder;
    }

}
```

Implementation of the rest client:

```
public class RestClient {

    private WebClient client;
    private String gatewayUrl;

    public RestClient(String gatewayUrl, String token, String username, String password, SslContext sslContext) {
        this.gatewayUrl = gatewayUrl;
        WebClient.Builder builder = WebClient.builder().baseUrl(gatewayUrl);
        if (sslContext != null) {
            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec.sslContext(sslContext));
            ClientHttpConnector httpConnector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
            builder.clientConnector(httpConnector);
        }
        if (username != null && password != null) {
            builder.filter(basicAuthentication(username, password));
        }
        client = builder.build();
    }

    public Mono<Void> executeOnly(ReportRequest transaction) {
        Mono<ReportRequest> transactionMono = Mono.just(transaction);
        return client.post().uri(gatewayUrl)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .body(transactionMono, ReportRequest.class)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Void.class);
    }
}
```

Make remote calls:

```
public class ReportingProcessor {

    private String URL2 = "......";

    public void collectEnvironmentData() throws JAXBException {

        ReportRequest report = new ReportRequest();
        report.setVersion("1.0");

        RestClient client = null;
        try {
            client = RestClientBuilder.builder()
                    .gatewayUrl(URL2)
//                .token(contract.getTerminal_token())
//                  .usernamePassword("user", "password")
//                .truststore(new File("server.pem"))
//                .sslCertificate(new File("client.pem"), new File("clientKey.p8"), "secret")
                    .build();
        } catch (SSLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Mono<Void> result = client.executeOnly(report);
        Void response = result.block();

    }
```

When I remove `Void response = result.block();` the request is not send. I Can't find why. Can you give me some advice how to make the client code working without using `block()`.

Comment: you have to call subscribe on that mono.. nothing happens until you subscribe

Comment: A publisher (Flux or Mono) doesn't do anything until you subscribe. This is a fundamental principle, well explained in the reactor doc, that you should read. block() subscribes and blocks the current thread until the publisher completes or throws.

Comment: can you show me a code snipped please how to fix this?

Comment: I added `.retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Void.class)
                .subscribe();` but again request is not send. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you give me some guide what part of the code to fix please?

Comment: Try Change Void response = result.block(); by result.subscribe();

Comment: I tried it - it's working if I also add `Thread.sleep(1000);`

Answer (score 3):

How I would implement your method is:

```java
public Mono<Void> executeOnly(ReportRequest transaction) {
    Mono<ReportRequest> transactionMono = Mono.just(transaction);
    return client.post().uri(gatewayUrl)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        .body(transaction, ReportRequest.class)
        .exchange()
        .then();
}
```

And then I would use it as follows:

`client.executeOnly(report).subscribe()`

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you work with Spring-webflux you have to keep one thing in mind. i.e You don't have to break your chain. because it is necessary to, someone should call subscribe on your chain. as it works on RXJava specification.

if you break the chain then you have to call `block()` which not **recommended**.

you have to modify your code in the below manner.

Let's Consider you have a handler which is making a call to your `collectEnvironmentData()` method and your method is making a call to remote service.

```
public  Mono<ServerResponse> handelerMethod(ServerRequest request){
  return collectEnvironmentData().flatMap(aVoid -> ServerResponse.ok().build());
}
```

your method should be modified to

```
public Mono<Void> collectEnvironmentData() throws JAXBException {

ReportRequest report = new ReportRequest();
report.setVersion("1.0");

RestClient client = null;
try {
    client = RestClientBuilder.builder()
            .gatewayUrl(URL2)
//                .token(contract.getTerminal_token())
//                  .usernamePassword("user", "password")
//                .truststore(new File("server.pem"))
//                .sslCertificate(new File("client.pem"), new File("clientKey.p8"), 
//"secret").build();
} catch (SSLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return client.executeOnly(report);
}
```

Change your implementation in the above manner, hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `method return type` to `Mono<Void>` for end to end streaming.

```
public void collectEnvironmentData() throws JAXBException {

    ReportRequest report = new ReportRequest();
    report.setVersion("1.0");

    RestClient client = null;
    try {
        client = RestClientBuilder.builder()
                .gatewayUrl(URL2)
                .build();
    } catch (SSLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return client.executeOnly(report);

}
```

Or you can also subscribe the `Mono`

```
client.executeOnly(report).subscribe();
```